# How to fix or ignore the following prettier error

Tags: eslint, prettier

What exactly is this prettier error?:
`error  Insert '·'  prettier/prettier`

Does it expect a space after () in?:
`beforeEach(function() {`

What's the way to ignore that in eslint/prettier?

Answer (score 0):

Prettier expects a space **before** the functions' `()`, i.e., between the word `function` and the opening parenthesis:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    // Here -------^
```

Comment: Is there a way to ignore that in prettier ?

Comment: @WQEQWEW how are you configuring prettier? via eslint? something else?

Comment: i have both eslintrc and prettierrc

Answer (score 0):

`Insert` ·`eslintprettier/prettier` is an error which you will get if you haven't given proper spacing. Here it denotes space by `.`

In your case, the prettier formatter expects you to give space in the function and `()` inside the `beforeEach()`. So changing your code from -

```
beforeEach(function() {
```

to

```
beforeEach(function () {
```

would solve the issue.

**Note:** In most text editors, you have the option to format on save by which you can set the text editor to automatically format the code as per the default formatted so that you won't need to worry about solving these issues. Once you save the document, your code will get auto-formatted.

Also, you can ignore if you don't want to format as per the change suggested. For eg. In VSCode, you will get options if you hover over the error -

[image]

You can choose to fix the problem, disable it for the line or even for entire file.